# How to create a generic list in this weird case in c#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types

In my program, I have a class `A` which is extended by `B`, `C` and many more classes. I have a method `GetInstance()` which returns an instance of `B` or `C` (or of one of the other children), but I don't know which one, so the return type of the method is `A`.

In the method `CreateGenericList()`, I have a variable `v` of type `A`, which is in fact either a `B`, a `C` or another child type and I want to create a generic list of the proper type, i.e. `List<B>` if `v` is a `B` or `List<C>` if `v` is a `C`, ...

Currently I do it by using reflection, which works, but this is extremely slow. I wanted to know if there is another way to do it, which doesn't use reflection.

Here is an example of the code of my problem:

```
class A { }  
class B : A { }  
class C : A { }
// More childs of A.


class Program
{
    static A GetInstance()
    {
        // returns an instance of B or C
    }

    static void CreateGenericList()
    {
        A v = Program.GetInstance();
        IList genericList = // Here I want an instance of List<B> or List<C> or ... depending of the real type of v, not a List<A>.
    }
}
```

I tried the following hack. I call the following method, hoping the type inferencer would  guess the type of `model`, but it doesn't work and returns a `List<A>`. I believe that because c# is statically typed, `T` is resolved as an `A` and not as the real type of `model` at run-time.

```
static List<T> CreateGenericListFromModel<T>(T model) where T : A
{
    return new List<T> ();
}
```

Does anybody have a solution to that problem that doesn't use reflection or that it is impossible to solve that problem without reflection?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Reflection is most probably only slow the first time you call the method, because the type information is loaded somehow. In my experience, the second call should be much faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't solve this Problem without reflection, as generic type parameters have to be known at compile time. If you know what type you have (eg. by `if(v[0] is B)`) you can use `v.Cast<B>()` to convert it from a `List<A>` to `IEnumerable<B>`, which you can turn into a list again by calling `ToList()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Unfortunately your advice won't work in my case, but at least now I'm sure it is not possible to do what I wanted without reflection.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a bit of a code smell to me. I would suggest that you need to go back to your design to think about why you would really need to do this. The reason this isn't simple to do is because what you are trying to do does violate object oriented principles.

If you are following the [SOLID](http://www.butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) principles, your code should never need to know if what it thought was class A was actually class B or class C.

How will it matter further down the line if your list is B or C? Do you have code like :

```
if (x is B)
{
  // do stuff to B
}
else
{
  // do stuff to C
}
```

If you do, then watch out. Avoid doing this! What should happen when you get class D that you have to handle as well?

I would suggest just using a List of A should be all you need to do. Any differences in functionality between B or C should be handled by overriding methods defined within A ([Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming)).

Comment: Actually, I have a good reason to use this design in this case, but it is not apparent in my simplified example. But you're right, in other cases I would avoid to do this kind of things.

Answer (score -1):

to expand on Femaref's anwerer what you are trying to do is make your `List<T>` contravariant over assignment C# 4 does have support for covariant and contravariant generic types. however...

in C# 4 List is covariant (you can assign a `List<B>` to a `List<A>` but not the other way around), before C# 4 `List<A>` and `List<B>` are seperate types and can't be use together at all (they are invariant over all operations)

however c# 4 does contain something which may help you. dynamic! you can (AFAIK) build a `List<dynamic>` instead of your `List<A>` which would then let you access each list item according to its runtime type rather than compiletime. this is essentially similar to the reflection way of doing things but the code would probably be a bit neater.

Comment: I cannot solve my problem with dynamic, but I can use the covariant property somewhere else in my code which removes that problem. So thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Classes do not support variance annotations, and even if they did,`List<T>` could not be covariant or contravariant since `T` is used as a parameter type of some methods and a return type of others.  `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant in .NET 4.0, however.